# Compare TFS 2012 and Subversion

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, tfs

NOTE: This question discusses TFS-**2012** vs SVN.  Similar (but not duplicate) questions compared earlier TFS versions.

From what I've found (on other questions and sites), Microsoft has fixed most of the earlier gripes (performance, features, etc) of the earlier versions of TFS (as compared to SVN).

What are the primary pros and cons between **Team Foundation Server 2012** and a **Subversion** solution (TortoiseSVN, VisualSVN, AnkhSVN)?  What TFS issues remain?  What does svn provide that just isn't available in TFS?